# restarting canvas slot game

Tags: javascript, html

i made a slot machine game with 3 buttons, play, stop, refresh.. the play button starts the spinning, the stop button stops the spin on selected images, i just need to add a refresh button to refresh the game, restart like it the window was just opened.

```
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="play" class="butn butn--stripe">spin</div>
  <div id="setStopAt" class="butn butn--stripe">stop</div>
  <div id="refresh" class="butn butn--stripe">refresh</div>
</div>
```

the html declaration of the buttons

```
Game.prototype.restart = function() {
  this.lastUpdate = new Date();
  this.speed1 = this.speed2 = this.speed3 = SLOT_SPEED
  // function locates id from items
  function _find(items, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].id == id) 
        return i;
      }
    }    
    // Clear stop locations
    this.stopped1 = false;
    this.stopped2 = false;
    this.stopped3 = false;
    // randomize reel locations
    this.offset1 = -parseInt(Math.random(ITEM_COUNT)) * SLOT_HEIGHT;
    this.offset2 = -parseInt(Math.random(ITEM_COUNT)) * SLOT_HEIGHT;
    this.offset3 = -parseInt(Math.random(ITEM_COUNT)) * SLOT_HEIGHT;

    $('#results').hide();
    game.increaseSpeed();
    this.state = 2;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to restart the canvas with the refresh button, after stopping the game

Comment: I mean you have a restart function right? Just bind the refreshbutton to the function? If that is not the solution then your question mght lack some relevant code/info

Answer (score 0):

If you are alright with a complete restart then binding `Program.restart();` to your restart button might be your best bet. Otherwise this may help;

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/organize-js-game-restart-button/